# How to resolve error when ajaxtoolkit 3.5 is used "The Controls collection cannot be modified..."

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

*Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).*

I am using it in Gridview's EditTemplate Field to show color with ajax 3.5

**This is my master page hierarchy**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Outer.master.cs" Inherits="Home" %>

<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Outer.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="FullMid.master.cs" Inherits="FullMid" %>

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/FullMid.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="StatusRoomMaster.aspx.cs" Inherits="StatusRoomMaster" %>
```

**Page where I am getting error**

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtColorCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ColorCode") %>'></asp:TextBox>                        
    <asp:ColorPickerExtender ID="txtColorCode_ColorPickerExtender" runat="server" 
        Enabled="True" OnClientColorSelectionChanged="colorChanged" 
        SampleControlID="txtColorCode" TargetControlID="txtColorCode">
    </asp:ColorPickerExtender>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

I am using it under *masterpage's -> masterpage's -> page*

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

I am using this in outer.master and no update panel has been used.

Comment: can you post more of the master page? specifically anything that uses inline code tags (<% %>).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Text='<%# Bind("ColorCode") %>'` in the markup, create an event handler of the GridView's `OnRowDataBound` event and set the colour programaticlly in there.  That will remove the need for the `<% ... %>` block and hence the error.

Comment: I tried removing this tag and tried using text="" it is still showing me error

Comment: Did you do a full rebuild?  If so that would either mean you are getting a spurious error "e.g. it is saying that you have `<% ... %>` code blocks when you don't or that you have other code blocks that you have not put in your example.

Comment: Dont know what is happening. Till yesterday everything was ok and working fine. But today when i made a new master page and converted old pages to run in this master page. Then these two pages which contain ColorPicketExtender Control gets hang up. As soon as i removes this control these two pages also start working fine.

Answer (score 0):

not AjaxControlToolkit error,check you header.
AjaxCotrolToolkit code is

```
foreach (Control c in header.Controls)
{
HtmlLink l = c as HtmlLink;
                if (null != l && styleSheet.Equals(l.Href, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    addIt = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
```